# My program raises EOFError for input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, eof

my code was working fine as .py, but had some issues with packaging as an onefile exe and i found the solution on GitHub by importing (Process, freeze_support) from multiprocessing, but now my code gives me an EOFError (EOF when reading a line) :
here's my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import requests
import multiprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import os
import random

def f():

  save_path = 'C:/Windows/System32'
  file_name = "Reg.txt"
  path = 'C:/Windows/System32/Reg.txt'
  isFile = os.path.isfile(path)

  if isFile==True:
    try:
        y = input("input number: ")
        x = int (y)
    except:
        print('enter valid phone number')

    try:
        while x>0:
            try:

                driver = uc.Chrome()
                driver.get('url')
                driver.maximize_window()
                time.sleep(3)    

                User_Id = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")

                User_Id.send_keys('2' + y)

                Next_Button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id').click()

                time.sleep(3)

                password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

                password.send_keys(y)

                time.sleep(2)

                password_next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
                password_next_button.click()
            except:
                driver.quit()
    except:
        driver.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   freeze_support()
   Process(target=f).start()
```

here's the EOFError I get:

```
input number: Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\GHunter SN.py", line 30, in f
 y = input("input number: ")
 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Try to summarise your problem. It's a rule of thumb. The longer your question the less precise it is. Identify what is causing the error and give some ideas and mention what the overall goal for the code is. It'll help others in solving it!

Answer (score 0):

This happens in multiprocessing whenever you take input. The builtin tries to read from `stdin`, but gets EOF immediately.

In fact, input does not exist at all, as shown here.

```py
>>> def function(stdin):
...     # a dumb implementation of input
...     return stdin.readline()
>>> Process(target=function, args=(sys.stdin,)).start()

Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in function
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

You have to gather the input before running multiprocessing (and `input` is blocking anyway, so it won't really hurt your performance).

```py
def f(x: int):
    while x > 0:
        try:
            driver = uc.Chrome()
            driver.get('url')
            driver.maximize_window()
            time.sleep(3)    

            User_Id = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
            User_Id.send_keys('2' + y)
            Next_Button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id').click()
            time.sleep(3)

            password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
            password.send_keys(y)
            time.sleep(2)

            password_next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
            password_next_button.click()
        except:
            driver.quit()

# ...
    save_path = 'C:/Windows/System32'
    file_name = "Reg.txt"
    path = 'C:/Windows/System32/Reg.txt'
    isFile = os.path.isfile(path)

    if isFile:
        # gather input
    Process(target=f, args=(x,)).start()
```